# Android: Making a Button Display Silly Text

Tags: java, android

I am creating an app in Android where I have a button that displays silly phrases when pressed.

I figured out how to get it to say two phrases but I can't figure out how to make it do more.

I also want to add in a feature to have the button pick phrases at random instead of going in the order I set.

I am thinking of using an array list for this.

How do I set the button to cycle through different methods in Android Studio?

I also want you to know that I am a beginner so please don't be too hard on me.

This is my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/funny_imageview"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/funny_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text=""/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/funny_sayings_button"
        android:text="Click Me!"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:onClick="changeFunnySayingsButton"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my Java:

```
package com.example.android.funnysayingsbutton;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
boolean clicked = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /**
     * This method changes the funny text and image on the screen when the button is clicked.
     */
    public void changeFunnySayingsButton (View view){
        if (clicked){
            funnySayingOne();
            clicked = false;
        }
        else {
            funnySayingTwo();
            clicked = true;
        }

    }

    /**
     * This method is for the first funny expression.
     */
    public void funnySayingOne(){
        displayAnswer("Time to Monkey Around");
        displayImage(R.drawable.monkey);
    }
    /**
     * This method is for the second funny expression.
     */
    public void funnySayingTwo(){
        displayAnswer("Penguin Party Time");
        displayImage(R.drawable.penguin);
    }

    /**
     * This method is for the third funny expression.
     */
    public void funnySayingThree(){
        displayAnswer("It's Rabbit Season.");
        displayImage(R.drawable.rabbit);
    }

    /**
     * This method displays the funny text on the screen.
     */
    private void displayAnswer(String answer) {
        TextView questionTextView = (TextView)    findViewById(R.id.funny_textview);
        questionTextView.setText(answer);
    }

    /**
     * This method displays the funny image on the screen.
     */
    private void displayImage(int picture) {
        ImageView questionTextView = (ImageView)    findViewById(R.id.funny_imageview);
        questionTextView.setImageResource(picture);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, where is your button onClick listener? This is where you should add your methods.

```
Button button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.funny_sayings_button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 changeFunnySayingsButton (v);
            }
        });
```

To continue with you could create an ArrayList of Strings. You add all of your strings and then simply pick one at random from the list. Hint:

```
//will choose a random number between 0 and the length of the list - 1
int i = rand.nextInt(yourList.size()); 
String yourFunnyString=yourList.get(i);
```

If you also want to display an image alongside with the String you should also create a map. Use the String as a key. When you select from yourList then use this key to select the value (your image) from the map.

It should be fairly straightforward to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're on the right track thinking about using a data structure like an `ArrayList`.

I'd start by making a class to represent each funny thing, e.g.

```
public class FunnyThing {
  private String phrase; // I'd use a resource ID here
  private int drawableResourceId;
}
```

Then it's a matter of initializing the set of `FunnyThing` objects and storing them in your data structure.  You could do this in the `onCreate` method of your activity, but you may want to consider writing a factory method somewhere else (e.g. the `FunnyThing` class) that your activity just calls to keep the code from getting cluttered when there are more than 2-3 funny things.

Finally, on each button press you can choose a random index in your collection of `FunnyThing`s and display that, e.g.

```
private void displayRandomFunnyThing() {
  // assumes you have a java.util.Random instance vairable named mRandom
  FunnyThing ft = mFunnyThings.get( mRandom.nextInt( mFunnyThings.size());
  displayAnswer( ft.phrase );
  displayImage( ft.drawableResourceId);
}
```

Of course you'll need to add an `onClickListener` to your button, but I'm assuming that you left that code out for brevity.

You'll also have the problem that the phrase selection is random, so you may get the same phrase many times before you see all of them.  If you want to prevent duplicates, well, that will take more code.